# How can i apply an interface to an anonymous callback function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an interface that looks like this

```
interface CallBackHandler{
 (err: Error, response: {statusCode: number, body: object}):void
}
```

and i want to apply that interface to the callback of this

```
    request({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: false,
    json: true,
    headers: headers
  }, (err, response) => {
    this.handleResponse(err, response, resolve, reject);
  });
```

but im getting a error saying the function must return something if the return type is not void when i add the interface

```
(err, response): CallBackHandler => {
    this.handleResponse(err, response, resolve, reject);
  }
```

what is the correct way to apply this interface?

Answer (score 1):

If `request()` already has the type signature:

```
function request(options, callback: CallBackHandler) {
   ...
}
```

Then you shouldn't need to do anything, as the callback you provide will be type-checked accordingly.

If that function *doesn't* already have that type signature, and you want to manually cast your callback to `CallBackHandler`, then you will need to wrap the callback function in parentheses and cast that expression, like so:

```
request({
    ...etc
}, ((err, response) => {
    this.handleResponse(err, response, resolve, reject);
}) as CallBackHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like

```
request({
  url: url,
  method: "GET",
  withCredentials: false,
  json: true,
  headers: headers
}, (err: Error, response: {statusCode: number, body: object}) => {
  this.handleResponse(err, response, resolve, reject);
});
```